# I can't read a mp3 file with unittest in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, file

I have a method with unittest, but i can't read a mp3 file, i'm try many ways to read

```
    def test_convert_audio(self):
        file = File(open("./assets/audio.mp3"))
        extension_name = convert_audio(file)
        print(extension_name)
        self.assertEqual('token', 'test')
```

Always response with

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
None
```

This is the method I am testing

```
def convert_audio(file):
    local_path = './audio_temp'
    download_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, (str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.wav'))
    path = save_blob_storage_audio(file)
    print(path)
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(path)
    return sound.export(download_file_path, format="wav")
```

I share the full traceback

```
speech_to_text_azure_test.py::SpeechToTextAzureTest::test_convert_audio FAILED [100%]Exception:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
None

speech_to_text_azure_test.py:36 (SpeechToTextAzureTest.test_convert_audio)
self = <speech_to_text_azure_test.SpeechToTextAzureTest testMethod=test_convert_audio>

    def test_convert_audio(self):
        file = File(open("./assets/audio.mp3"))
>       extension_name = convert_audio(file)

speech_to_text_azure_test.py:39: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\..\speech_to_text_azure.py:52: in convert_audio
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(path)
..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py:796: in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

cls = <class 'pydub.audio_segment.AudioSegment'>, file = None, format = 'mp3'
codec = None, parameters = None, start_second = None, duration = None
kwargs = {}, orig_file = None, close_file = False
is_format = <function AudioSegment.from_file.<locals>.is_format at 0x000002332429C598>

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, file, format=None, codec=None, parameters=None, start_second=None, duration=None, **kwargs):
        orig_file = file
        try:
            filename = fsdecode(file)
        except TypeError:
            filename = None
        file, close_file = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(file, 'rb', tempfile=False)
    
        if format:
            format = format.lower()
            format = AUDIO_FILE_EXT_ALIASES.get(format, format)
    
        def is_format(f):
            f = f.lower()
            if format == f:
                return True
    
            if filename:
                return filename.lower().endswith(".{0}".format(f))
    
            return False
    
        if is_format("wav"):
            try:
                if start_second is None and duration is None:
                    return cls._from_safe_wav(file)
                elif start_second is not None and duration is None:
                    return cls._from_safe_wav(file)[start_second*1000:]
                elif start_second is None and duration is not None:
                    return cls._from_safe_wav(file)[:duration*1000]
                else:
                    return cls._from_safe_wav(file)[start_second*1000:(start_second+duration)*1000]
            except:
                file.seek(0)
        elif is_format("raw") or is_format("pcm"):
            sample_width = kwargs['sample_width']
            frame_rate = kwargs['frame_rate']
            channels = kwargs['channels']
            metadata = {
                'sample_width': sample_width,
                'frame_rate': frame_rate,
                'channels': channels,
                'frame_width': channels * sample_width
            }
            if start_second is None and duration is None:
                return cls(data=file.read(), metadata=metadata)
            elif start_second is not None and duration is None:
                return cls(data=file.read(), metadata=metadata)[start_second*1000:]
            elif start_second is None and duration is not None:
                return cls(data=file.read(), metadata=metadata)[:duration*1000]
            else:
                return cls(data=file.read(), metadata=metadata)[start_second*1000:(start_second+duration)*1000]
    
        conversion_command = [cls.converter,
                              '-y',  # always overwrite existing files
                              ]
    
        # If format is not defined
        # ffmpeg/avconv will detect it automatically
        if format:
            conversion_command += ["-f", format]
    
        if codec:
            # force audio decoder
            conversion_command += ["-acodec", codec]
    
        read_ahead_limit = kwargs.get('read_ahead_limit', -1)
        if filename:
            conversion_command += ["-i", filename]
            stdin_parameter = None
            stdin_data = None
        else:
            if cls.converter == 'ffmpeg':
                conversion_command += ["-read_ahead_limit", str(read_ahead_limit),
                                       "-i", "cache:pipe:0"]
            else:
                conversion_command += ["-i", "-"]
            stdin_parameter = subprocess.PIPE
>           stdin_data = file.read()
E           AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py:723: AttributeError
```

Comment: What is the exact traceback message? They would normally show the line number, function name and file where the error occurred. You code doesn't contain rstrip so can't see what is wrong with the little code you have provided. Can you provide a short executable example?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Python and its modules/functions don't behave differently just because they are executed as part of a unittest either. This doesn't rule out monkey-patching in internal modules, but it's unlikely. Please, for a start, extract and provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].